# Comprehensive and customized error report from Android apps

Tags: android, logging, error-handling

I would like to know if there is a way in Android to have the application create an information-richer error report in case of a crash.

I'm starting Android development, so I haven't published anything to the Market yet, but I have read some documentation, including this [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html), about error reporting.
My conclusion looks like the fact that error reports are almost mere stack traces, and while the user has the option to attach system logs, they are analysed by Google only and not by the application developer.
I would like to know if I'm able to attach an application log to the error report. For example, when my software parses an HTML page to grab strings, I would like to attach the full HTML body together with any parsing error that may appear (suppose the website changes some tags... and suppose the site is on a private network that is difficult for me to continuously monitor for page changes).

In general, starting from this example, I would like to read a debug log to help me better understand the circumstances that made the error occur.

Is that possible? And how? I'm not sure that Android [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class is useful even after deployment.

Comment: Bugsense and ACRA provide a more detailed report than the android market does. And you won't have to rely on the user opting on reporting the crashes.

Comment: An option is surely to use log4j or slf4j to log, protect all code with try/catch and in case of error try to send the logfile to the developer directly via email. Not the smartest idea. Requires SD CARD and INTERNET privileges

Comment: "I would like to know if I'm able to attach an application log to the error report" -- it is possible via something like ACRA but is considered poor form for privacy reasons. "when my software parses an HTML page to grab strings, I would like to attach the full HTML body together" -- depending on who chooses the HTML to be parsed, this might also be a privacy violation.

Comment: @Woodsy do these work when the phone is offline too? AFAIK default Google behaviour is to cache error report when phone is offline. My app is going to work without internet access (but with INTERNET permissions)

Comment: @CommonsWare +1, you are correct. But letting the user opt in for sharing useful debug information rather getting a negative feedback. That's the rule of informed consent. A good developer would also put a warning about that. And definitely I would not be going to request user-identifiable information in the error report, but instead better status reports encoded in the HTML, which is my real target

Comment: @djechelon I don't know for sure but I assume it will need network access when the crash occurs.

Comment: @Woodsy seems ACRA provides email option, which is exactly the kind of asynchronousness I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate better error reports by using external frameworks.

One of this frameworks is [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com/). Crittercism lets you add breadcrumbs and additional data to crashes. This should enable you to log most of the things you need to know to find bugs that are happening in the wild.